# Ajax code for the counterpart of success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this code to do autocomplete function from database. what if the input is not in database, how can i show the error message?

this is my js code:

```
$('#txt_fname').autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'under the hood/rehabCreateAjax.php',
            dataType: "json",
            method: 'post',
            data: {
               name_startsWith: request.term,
               type: 'country_table',
               row_num : 1
            },
             success: function( data ) {
                 response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    var code = item.split("|");
                    return {
                        label: code[0],
                        value: code[0],
                        data : item
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    autoFocus: true,            
    minLength: 0,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        var names = ui.item.data.split("|");                        
        $('#txt_mname').val(names[1]);
        $('#txt_sname').val(names[2]);
        $('#txt_nickname').val(names[3]);
        $('#txt_stuNum').val(names[4]);
    }               
});
```

this is my php code:

```
require_once '../connection/dbConn.php';
if($_POST['type'] == 'country_table'){
    $row_num = $_POST['row_num'];
    $name = $_POST['name_startsWith'];
    $query = "SELECT stu_fname, stu_mname, stu_sname, stu_nickname,     student_id FROM student 
                    where (UPPER(stu_fname) LIKE '".strtoupper($name)."%')      or (UPPER(stu_mname) LIKE '".strtoupper($name)."%') or
                     (UPPER(stu_sname) LIKE '".strtoupper($name)."%') or     (UPPER(stu_nickname) LIKE '".strtoupper($name)."%')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $name =     $row['stu_fname'].'|'.$row['stu_mname'].'|'.$row['stu_sname'].'|'.$row['stu_nick    name'].'|'.$row['student_id'].'|'.$row_num;
        array_push($data, $name);   
    }   
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

by the way..i have tried to put else in my php code.. not working.

Comment: Use `sucess: function(){...............},error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
}`

Comment: `success` indicates that the HTTP request itself was successful, not that the server-side functionality was successful. You need something within your success callback that handles a non-ideal result.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly you want to respond to an empty results set, and not to some sort of server error. If this is the case you should include it in your `success` callback. simply check in your client code if the `data` array has items and respond accordingly:

```
     success: function( data ) {
      if (data.length) {
         response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    var code = item.split("|");
                    return {
                        label: code[0],
                        value: code[0],
                        data : item
                    }
                }));
            } else {
                console.log("no results");
            }
       }
```

The `error` callback suggested by @Koogle is not meant for this purpose, and you definitely should not return a `404` from the server, which is only used when the url itself is not found (or for that matter a `500`, which implies an internal server error).

The `error` callback represents a *low-level* failure to get a response from the server, and is automatically ran by `JQuery` if the request failed. It should not be forced to run by returning an error code for a successful request (`200`). The error you are referring to is *high-level*, because it stems from the inherent *logic* of your code, and not from an objective failure to execute the code itself for whatever reason.

Thus, the label `error` in your case is dictated by the way you perceive the logic of your code. e.g if you are filtering results in a table and the filter doesn't return any results, this can hardly qualify as an error. However, if you expect that the request would always return at least one result, then `error` may be justified, although I believe that `exception` is the more accurate term.

Answer (score 0):

You could respond in your php script with an HTTP error message and handle the error in JS as follows:

```
  $.ajax({
        url : 'under the hood/rehabCreateAjax.php',
        dataType: "json",
        method: 'post',
        data: {
           name_startsWith: request.term,
           type: 'country_table',
           row_num : 1
        },
         success: function( data ) {
             response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                var code = item.split("|");
                return {
                    label: code[0],
                    value: code[0],
                    data : item
                }
            }));
           error: function (response) {
                  // Handle error here
                  console.log(response);
           }
        }
```

The PHP should be something like:

```
$query = "SELECT stu_fname, stu_mname, stu_sname, stu_nickname,     student_id FROM student 
                where (UPPER(stu_fname) LIKE '".strtoupper($name)."%')      or (UPPER(stu_mname) LIKE '".strtoupper($name)."%') or
                 (UPPER(stu_sname) LIKE '".strtoupper($name)."%') or     (UPPER(stu_nickname) LIKE '".strtoupper($name)."%')";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);


$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $name =     $row['stu_fname'].'|'.$row['stu_mname'].'|'.$row['stu_sname'].'|'.$row['stu_nick    name'].'|'.$row['student_id'].'|'.$row_num;
    array_push($data, $name);   
}
// Respond with error
if($data.length() == 0) {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo "No such entry";
    return;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: I will add in a moment